# Configuring PlayWright and Jest returns 'Playwright Test needs to be invoked via 'npx playwright test' and excluded from Jest test runs'

Tags: jestjs, playwright, playwright-test

I've tried configuring Jest into my Playwright project, so far I've done this

```
npm init && npm install -D jest jest-playwright-preset playwright
```

and then added a file called

> jest.config.js

which contains

```
module.exports = {
rootDir: '.',
testTimeout: 20000,
testMatch: [
  '<rootDir>/*.spec.js'
],
preset: 'jest-playwright-preset'}
```

and added to my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "projeto_pessoal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "teste api",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.32.3",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-playwright-preset": "^3.0.1",
    "playwright": "^1.32.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "unnamed",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Yet, running npm test returns this error message:

> Playwright Test needs to be invoked via 'npx playwright test' and
> excluded from Jest test runs.
> Creating one directory for Playwright tests and one for Jest is the recommended way of doing it.
> See https://playwright.dev/docs/intro for more information about Playwright Test.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. What about it is problematic? What is your goal, exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen--onLLMstrike The problem is that the error message is asking him to run the tests in the Playwright Runner instead of in Jest, and he (presumably) doesn't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that what you want to do is to run tests that are generated using `playwright codegen` with Jest.

However, this does not seem to be possible: The tests are generated with `import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test'` at the top, and this is the module that throws the error. The tests that are generated with Playwright use the API from this module, and this is slightly different than the one from Jest. (It gets fixtures as parameters).

If you use the implementation from Playwright (for instance by mocking away the `throwIfRunningInsideJest` function), it still won't work because then the tests won't be registered in the Jest test runner.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @playwright/test from the package.json devDependencies.

To write tests see [expect-playwright](https://github.com/playwright-community/expect-playwright) which is pre-installed with jest-playwright.

Comment: I think what he wants to do is to run a codegen'd test inside Jest, and the test will automatically import @playwright/test in the header.